# canonical quotient map on lie group is proper?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be Lie group and $K \subset G$ a compact Lie subgroup of $G$.
Let $\pi \colon G \to G/K , \quad g \mapsto g.K=[g]$ denote the canonical projection on the quotient and endow $G/K$ with the quotient-topology.

Is $\pi$ then a proper map?

Edit:
As I tried to solve it, I used a step I'm not quite sure if it is true.

So let $V \subset G/K$ be a compact subset. Let $(g_j)_j \subset \pi^{-1}(V) =:U$ be sequence. If I now find a convergent subsequence of $(g_j)_j$, then $U$ is compact and $\pi$ proper.
Since $\pi(g_j)_j \subset V$ is a sequence and $V$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence $(\pi(g_{j_n}))_{j_n}=(g_{j_n}.K)_{j_n} \to g_0.K$. And we assume form now on, that $(\pi(g_j))_j$ is that convergent sequence.

Now comes the part I'm not quite sure:
Since $(g_j.K)_j \to g_0.K$, we find a sequence $(k_j)_j \subset K$ such that $g_jk_j \to x_0$ with $x_0.K = g_0.K$ $\textbf{(So do we really find such elements $k_j$?).}$

If we find such a sequence in $K$, we can again use, that $K$ is compact and we find a convergent subsequence $(k_{j_n})_n \to k_0$. Again identify the subsequence with the full sequence and we get:
$$g_n = g_n(k_n k^{-1}_n)=(g_nk_n)k_n^{-1} \to x_0k_0^{-1}$$
since the action is continous and so $k_n^{-1} \to k_0^{-1}$.

And we found a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is proper. Let $C$ be a compact subset of $G/K$ and $(U_i)$ an open cover of $p^{-1}(C)$ without restricting the generality, you can suppose that the adherence $V_i$ of $U_i$ is compact. You can extract a finite family $W_1,...,W_n$ from $p(U_i)$ which covers $C$ where $p:G\rightarrow G/K$ is the natural quotient map. Write $W_i=p(A_i)$ where $A_i$ is an element of the family $(U_i)$. Since the adherence $B_i$ of $A_i$ is compact, the Union $D=\bigcup_i B_iK$ is also compact. You deduce that $p^{-1}(C)$ is a closed subset contained in the compact set $D$ so it is compact.

Comment: 1) Thank you for your answer, 2) what does "adherence" mean in this context?

Comment: The adherence of A is the smallest closed subset which contains A

Comment: I'm not sure, why we can just assume that the closure of $U_i$ is compact... Furthermore, I'm not sure why $p^{-1}(C) \subset D$ as $\pi$ isn't injective in general.

Comment: I suppose that the Lie group is finite dimensional in this case so it is locally compact , you can find a refinement $(V_j)$ of $(U_i)$ such that $V_j$ is compact. $p^{-1}(C)$ is contained in $D$, since $p(C)$ contains $C$ and is saturated.

Comment: Let $x\in p^{-1}(C)$, $p(x)\in C$, thus $p(x)\in W_i$, so $x\in p^{-1}(W_i)=A_iK\subset B_iK\subset D.$

Comment: The sets $p(U_i)$ are open because quotient maps between topological groups are open (unlike quotient maps in general).